# Does ToString() method violates SRP?

Tags: c#, java, oop, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

As the title states, why any object should inherit the ToString() method (in C# or Java for example) and in some way care to convert it to String? Isn't this, in some cases, a violation of the Single Responsability Principle? I mean, if your object doesn't need to be converted to string you will end up having more responsabilities for your object.

Comment: I disagree that all classes should define the `toString()` method.  Personally, when writing a public API, I define a `toString()` method in all classes for the sake of other developers, but when developing internals, I only define it if necessary, therefore following SRP.

Comment: Does an object violate SRP by defining its *very own* particular way of being represented as a `String` when required? IMHO it's not about SRP per se, but about an object's required features.

Comment: @Vulcan I was not saying that any objects have to redefine the ToString(), but anyway they must have that method even if a specific sub-type shouldn't have the responsability to "convert" its value to string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a sense, `ToString()` does violate the single responsibility principle.  Converting to a string representation should not *necessarily* be a requirement of each and every object type.  In C#, `GetHashCode()` is arguably worse - and again, defined on every type.  This could easily have been done via some other mechanism (ie: an optional interface, and a class with the single responsibility of converting any object into a string, etc).

It's a matter of practicality vs. correctness.  Having a method on every object which provides a string representation (arguably) makes some things simpler overall, at the expense of having each object implement it.  That being said, objects do not need to take on this responsibility if they are happy with the default implementation.

Comment: Any class object `X` should be able to determine whether any of its members could ever behave differently from those of the object referred to by `Y` (any class which implements `Equals` using reference equality would meet that description, since if `X` and `Y` are distinct objects, calling `.Equals(X)` on `X` and `Y` will yield different results).  The usefulness of the equivalence relation provided by `Equals` can be greatly enhanced by having a `GetHashCode()` method that's consistent with it.

Comment: Even if it might make sense semantically to have code that wants to compare objects use a comparison method when one is provided, and test reference equality when one is not, unconditionally calling a virtual method which is known to exist is faster than testing whether an object has a virtual method that it may or may not have].

Comment: What do you mean when you say `an optional interface` - you mean a marker interface? If not, what methods will be in this interface signature?